# Models using Unity URP shader and transparency are overlapping themselves

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, rendering, transparency, urp

I am trying to make a scene where the player can get in and out of a transparent sphere while fighting. The problem is that for the trees I need to use another transparent material so I can use pngs without the background showing.
I tried standard URP materials and custom shader graph materials, but I don't know how to fix this problem exactly.
From what I searched, it is a common problem for transparency overlap, but are there some workarounds for this case?

Here are some images of the issue:
[Problem seen from outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJKEt.png)
[Problem seen from inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcCqG.png)

Building for Android (iOS in the future in mind)
Unity version: 2021.1.18

I thought it might be because of my custom shader so I also tried with a standard URP material, as I mentioned, but I have the same problems:

[URP material1 test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv0YW.jpg)
[URP material2 test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b1E2.jpg)

I also tried to change the render queue and material priorities, but since the objects can be seen from both perspectives, it doesn't help much.
Objects with opaque materials work as intended, and so would the foliage but they would have the png background visible:
[Opaque foliage example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUshs.png)